# Laravel model path autoloading showing error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Created models inside one folder called TP and processed composer dump-autoload. But got this error.

> Deprecation Notice: Class App\Models\Company located in ./app/Models/TP/Company.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201

Folder structure is App\Models\TP\Company.php

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Company extends Model
    {
      protected $table = 'tbl_company';
    }
```

I am getting error in application

```
"message": "Class \"App\\Models\\TR\\SessionUser\" not found",
```

Comment: please fix your namspace `  namespace App\Models\TP;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change namespace as per PSR4 standard

```
 namespace App\Models\TP;
```

So it should be

```
<?php

    namespace App\Models\TP;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Company extends Model
    {
      protected $table = 'tbl_company';
    }
```

[image]

Ref:https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/